# Get time value from textbox and perform calculations?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to retrieve a time value from a textbox and perform calculations on it.

Use case example: User inputted time (8:00 am) - (30 minutes)

I'm getting the value by the getElementById method, but I am unsure how to make it read in a proper time format and do the calculations.

Could someone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: it's a little unclear what you want to achieve. Do you expect the user to feed time and arythmetic operations on it? in your example -substract 30 minuets from 08:00 am?

Comment: Can the format be anything or is it fixed to "(TIME) - (X MINUTES)"

Comment: Yes, I need to make a textbox area where the user can input a time, say 8:00 am and then I need to take that value and subtract different time intervals from it. So for example take 8:00 am and subtract 30 minutes, 60 minutes, and 90 minutes and give the results 7:30, 7:00 and 6:30.